# Creating a new column in Pandas by selecting part of string in other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a lot of experience programming in Matlab, now using Python and I just don't get this thing to work... I have a dataframe containing a column with timecodes like 00:00:00.033.

```
timecodes = ['00:00:01.001', '00:00:03.201', '00:00:09.231', '00:00:11.301', '00:00:20.601', '00:00:31.231', '00:00:90.441', '00:00:91.301']
df = pd.DataFrame(timecodes, columns=['TimeCodes'])
```

All my inputs are 90 seconds or less, so I want to create a column with just the seconds as float. To do this, I need to select position 6 to end and make that into a float, which I can do for the first row like:

```
float(df['TimeCodes'][0][6:])
```

This works just fine, but if I now want to create a whole new column 'Time_sec', the following does not work:

```
df['Time_sec'] = float(df['TimeCodes'][:][6:])
```

Because df['TimeCodes'][:][6:] takes row 6 to last row, while I want WITHIN each row the 6th till last position. Also this does not work:

```
 df['Time_sec'] = float(df['TimeCodes'][:,6:])
```

Do I need to make a loop? There must be a better way... And why does df['TimeCodes'][:][6:] not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `slice` string method and then cast the whole thing to a float:

```
In [13]: df["TimeCodes"].str.slice(6).astype(float)
Out[13]:
0     1.001
1     3.201
2     9.231
3    11.301
4    20.601
5    31.231
6    90.441
7    91.301
Name: TimeCodes, dtype: float64
```

As to why `df['TimeCodes'][:][6:]` doesn't work, what this ends up doing is chaining some selections. First you grab the `pd.Series` associated with the `TimeCodes` column, then you select all of the items from the Series with `[:]`, and then you just select the items with index 6 or higher with `[6:]`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution - [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) and casting to `float` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
print (df["TimeCodes"].str[6:])
0    01.001
1    03.201
2    09.231
3    11.301
4    20.601
5    31.231
6    90.441
7    91.301
Name: TimeCodes, dtype: object

df['new'] = df["TimeCodes"].str[6:].astype(float)
print (df)
      TimeCodes     new
0  00:00:01.001   1.001
1  00:00:03.201   3.201
2  00:00:09.231   9.231
3  00:00:11.301  11.301
4  00:00:20.601  20.601
5  00:00:31.231  31.231
6  00:00:90.441  90.441
7  00:00:91.301  91.301
```